# Infinite redirects at front end if logged in user is not an Admin (Toolset Access)

Tags: user-roles, user-access

I bought the toolset access plugin to handle specific user roles for languages. Once I log in as a user - which is not an admin - can be any like editor, contributor etc. The front end will not be loaded - it will lead to an infinite reload, until it crashes.

I tried to talk to toolset, but so far their answers take a long time and did not help yet.

Any idea where I can start debugging this?

I only can load the page again, if I manually delete the wordpress login cookies.
For non-logged-in users everything works fine.

Thanks for any type of help

Comment: The [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin adds stack traces to redirects so you can see what triggers the redirect. If you can catch the redirect response in your browser debug tools that'll show you where the problem is, else you might need to e.g. use `curl -D - ` and give curl your login cookie to reproduce this.

Comment: Obviously Toolset should be helping you with this though as you're a paying customer. Sorry to hear they haven't been much use.

Comment: Dear @rup thanks for your answer. I installed Query Monitor and check it by using the following steps. (I put this here in case someone is facing similar problems in the future)
---
- installed Plugin Query Monitor
- QM -> Settings "Set authentication cookie" 
- Logged out as Admin
- Logged in as another user
- Opened the /home page
- I get many redirects leading into a 301 
- QM is not showing up 
- I can only see QM in the backend but not in the frontend 

---

Comment: With curl -D (and using the login cookies) I also only get a 301 as response 
So far not luck :(

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was in the plugin. I had to set the read privilege for the user. But I was not really able to debug it. I just was trying around. I wish I could understand to step by step debug those type of problem for future problems.

Comment: Hopefully you'd have found that the redirect was being triggered by permissions code then. But if there wasn't any useful information on the redirect logging I'm not sure how you'd have done that.